# Create an Array with Keys and Values from database

Tags: c#

I need to do this in my codes;

1. Get data from 2 columns in a database (laborer and trx_date)
2. Place the extracted data to a DataTable
3. Explode the first column in the DataTable
4. Place exploded_laborer and trx_date to an array with

   ```
   key->exploded_laborer
   exploded=>trx_date
   ```

I am able to get to number 3 I just need to do number 4. My code is below:

```
private void GetLocalData()
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT laborer, trx_date from tbl_jobs WHERE trx_date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate";
    var laborerDataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var conn = new SqliteAccess().ConnectToSqlite())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", dtpFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", dtpTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            laborerDataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    var exploded = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in laborerDataTable.Rows)
    {

        exploded.Add(row["laborer"].ToString().Split('|')[0]);
    }
}
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What you meant by this: `I am able to get to number 3 I just need to do number 4. My code is below:` could you please be more clear?

Comment: I am able to do steps 1 - 3. I just don't know how to code the step 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are supposed to create [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) which represents a collection of keys and values. This might do the trick for you

```
laborerDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => laborerDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .ToDictionary(column => row[laborer] as string
                                      column => row[trx_date] as string))
```

Thus the complete code might look like

```
private void GetLocalData()
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT laborer, trx_date from tbl_jobs WHERE trx_date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate";
    var laborerDataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var conn = new SqliteAccess().ConnectToSqlite())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", dtpFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", dtpTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            laborerDataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    var LabDict = laborerDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => laborerDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .ToDictionary(column => row[laborer] as string
                                      column => row[trx_date] as string))
}
```

**Edit**

This is just to create a dummy table.

```
static DataTable GetTable()
{
    // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("laborer", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("trx_date", typeof(string));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add("Indocin", "12/12/2010");
    table.Rows.Add("Enebrel", "12/1/2011");
    table.Rows.Add("Hydralazine", "1/12/2012");
    table.Rows.Add("Combivent", "11/12/2013");
    table.Rows.Add("Dilantin", "12/11/2014");

    return table;
}
```

> normal core C# way

```
DataTable laborerDataTable = GetTable(); 
Dictionary<string, string> exploded = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(DataRow row in laborerDataTable.Rows)
{
    exploded.Add(row.Field<string>(0), row.Field<string>(1));
}
```

> Also, how do I print each of the row to a console?

```
foreach(var dct in exploded)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dct.Key + " Date is " + dct.Value);
}
```

Comment: Mohit, can you please show me in the normal core C# way. I do not know how to use linq yet. Also, how do I print each of the row to a console? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `normal core C# way` should you want to use `Dictionary` or not? if yes than we can do that in the loop as well.

Comment: If this is LINQ then I wouldn't understand it please make it a simple loop. Thanks. But if this is not a LINQ then I guess this the only way to do it or if you can make it more understandable. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Ibanez1408 I have updated the solution. please have a look if this piece of code is understandable or you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the result to a Key-Value pair then why an array? why not a `Dictionary<string, string>`? You can try something like this :

```
 Dictionary<string, string> laborerDict = laborerDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Field<string>("laborer"), 
                                                                        x => x.Field<string>("trx_date"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in built HashMap in java refer the code below
 HashMap map = new HashMap<>();
Map.put(key,value);
And to get data from map use
Map.get(key)
It has a lot of function, maybe you can refer them by searching Java API

Answer (score 0):

when you want to have Key=>Value better you use Dictionary instead of List

```
var exploded = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (DataRow row in laborerDataTable.Rows)
{
 exploded.Add(row["laborer"].ToString(),(row["trx_date"].ToString());
}
```